# Best Practices for CORS for Angular 2+ and Node/Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

I'm implementing user authentication right now using Express/Node, and I am testing the cookies from an Angular frontend.

After logging in, the cookies appear in the network tab as they should but they are not in the application tab. To solve this, I know I need to use the cors npm package. However, there was a way around this by setting up a proxy using proxy.conf.json. What is the best practice for doing this, using npm CORS in the backend or making it the "same origin" using a proxy?

I'm very new to doing this sort of thing, I literally just heard of CORS the other day.

A question popped into my head: Why am I able to access the APIs I set up in the backend without setting up CORS? I thought it was supposed to block anything that wasn't from the same origin. Example: I can login the user and get the correct JSON response back.

Comment: CORS are not something you can implement.

Comment: I meant using the cors npm package in the backend

Comment: i don't know what you meant, but i know what you wrote

Comment: Okay, I made a few edits. Do you have any insight on my questions?

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I able to access the APIs I set up in the backend without setting up CORS

Because CORS rules are enforced by **browser** not by server

If you must use foreign resources, either use simple requests (that CORS rules will allow) or use backend proxy.